# Pipeline fails when addng ReadAllFromText transform

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to run a very simple program in Apache Beam to try out how it works.

```
import apache_beam as beam


class Split(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        return element


with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    rows = (p | beam.io.ReadAllFromText(
        "input.csv") | beam.ParDo(Split()))
```

While running this, I get the following errors

```
.... some more stack....
 File "/home/raheel/code/beam-practice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/util.py", line 565, in expand
    windowing_saved = pcoll.windowing
  File "/home/raheel/code/beam-practice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py", line 137, in windowing
    self.producer.inputs)
  File "/home/raheel/code/beam-practice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 464, in get_windowing
    return inputs[0].windowing
  File "/home/raheel/code/beam-practice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py", line 137, in windowing
    self.producer.inputs)
  File "/home/raheel/code/beam-practice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 464, in get_windowing
    return inputs[0].windowing
AttributeError: 'PBegin' object has no attribute 'windowing'
```

Any Idea what is wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ReadAllFromText`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py#L423) expects to read from a PCollection of files instead of passing it as an argument. So, in your case, it should be:

```py
p | beam.Create(["input.csv"])
  | beam.io.ReadAllFromText()
```